# checkboxlist with prechecked in struts2

Tags: select, struts2, checkboxlist

I am trying to display checkboxlist with prechecked items.
The values are saved in a list in my database and for "editing" the user should be able to select new options as well as "uncheck" some of the earlier selected one.
Thats why I need to translate my List back to the checkboxlist...

Any idea how that could possibly work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/502158/Struts/pre-selected-checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example of how you can do it.

[1]edit.jsp page:

It is the page where you want to display your checked checkboxlist:

```
<s:checkboxlist name="type" list="typeList" />
```

here "type" is name of checkbox and "typeList" is a list which is loaded from actionclass in my case.

[2]loadEditData method in action class:

```
public class your_action_class_name extends ActionSupport {
     private List<String> type;
    private List<String> typeList;
    public List<String> getType() {
        return type;}
    public void setType(List<String> type) {
                this.type = type;}
    public List<String> getTypeList() {
        return typeList;
    }

    public void setTypeList(List<String> typeList) {
        this.typeList = typeList;
    }


    public String loadEditData(){
                tpyeList=\\add whole checkboxlist here;
                type.add("value that you want to prechecked");
                return SUCCESS;
    }
  }
```

[3]struts.xml:

```
 <action name="edit" method="loadEditData" class="your_action_class_Name" > 
    <result name="success">/edit.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Now your flow is like follow:

1st call the edit Action that will implement loadEditData method and on returning success display edit.jsp page with checkboxlist which have prechecked value.

Is this answer helpful?

Comment: I implemented it exactly thsi way, but it is not working :( my type is named ownKeywords and I do an addAll(keywords). and keywords is filled with: publication.geyKeyword() and it is really filled. but still nothing checked in my JSP